# Call multi fields by php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I call `size` and `megabyte` together?
I am using this code, but it dose not work, at all.

```html
<?php if( get_field('size' , 'megabyte'  )):?>
<span class="right">Size: <?php the_field('size' , 'megabyte' );?></span>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php if ( get_field( 'size' ) && get_field( 'megabyte' ) ) { ?>
         <span class="right">Size: <?php the_field('size');?><?php the_field('megabyte');?></span>      
    <?php }?>
```

The `&&` operator is equivalent to "and".